# GCC incompatible pointer type warning with intrinsic functions

Tags: c, gcc

The type of `a->data` is `uint64_t *`.  I looked it up in the header file and `uint64_t` is defined as `unsigned long int`.  I want to use the `_addcarryx_u64` function.  The last parameter of this function according to the header file is of type `unsigned long long *`.

In both are unsigned 64 bit integers.  However technically they are different and I keep getting annoying warnings like this...

```
warning: passing argument 4 of ‘_addcarryx_u64’ from incompatible pointer type

char c = _addcarryx_u64(0, a->data[0], b, a->data);
```

How can I either fix this or disable the warning.  I know I could cast my pointer but I like to code in a somewhat compile independent manner and `addcarryx` could be defined differently on another system.

Also on a side note I noticed that my gcc version only supports `addcarryx` and not plain `addcarry`.  Any reason why?

Also just so you know I am running GCC 4.9 compiling on ubuntu.  I have `-std=gnu99` set.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to cast, I suggest you write your own wrapper function that converts `a->data` to the correct type and then passes a pointer to that:

```
struct a_struct {
    /* ... */
    uint64_t *data;
};

char addcarry_u64(int x, struct a_struct *a, int b) {
    unsigned long long data = *a->data;
    return _addcarryx_u64(0, a->data[0], b, &data);
}
```